# JDE-mode indent 4 spaces

Tags: emacs, jde

In my .emacs file, I have a c-common-mode-hook that sets c-basic-offset to 4, but whenever I create a java file this is reset to 2.  How do I set indentation to four spaces in JDE mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, worst case, you customize java-mode via a hook:

```
(defun my-java-mode-setup ()
  "force c-basic-offset to be 4"
  (setq c-basic-offset 4))
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'my-java-mode-setup)
```

Debugging why your basic hook setting doesn't stick will require more information than you've given us.  I'm doing what you describe and see the offset to be 4 in java files.  It could be that you're using a built-in style that sets the offset to 2 after your common hook.  See [this documentation](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Adding-Styles.html) for how to customize styles.